# Probability question, confusion about with vs without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say this is the question:
An bowl contains 6 green and 8 yellow balls.  Five balls are drawn without replacement.  What is the probability that 3 are green and 2 are yellow? Order does not matter.

The way I interpretted this was: out of 6 green balls, I can choose 3, and then out of 8 yellow, choose 2. so I can calculate this as :

$$\frac {\binom 63\times \binom 82}{\binom {14}{5}}$$

First, is this correct? and second, how would this change if it were with replacement?

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  With replacement, this is just a binomial distribution problem...with success probability $\frac 6{14}$ you want exactly $3$ successes in $5$  trials.

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: Viewing Yellow as success, in R: (a) `dnyper(2, 8,6, 5)` returns  $0.2797203$ and `dbinom(2, 5, 8/14)` returns $0.2570358.$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the probability for obtaining 3 from 6 green balls and 2 from 8 yellow balls when selecting any 5 from all 14 balls without replacement is as you had.
The count for green balls has a *hypergeometric distribution*$$\dfrac{\dbinom 63\dbinom 82}{\dbinom {14}5}$$

When that selection is made without replacement, the probability is for any arrangement of 3 successes and 2 failures when the success rate is $6/14$. The count for successes has a *binomial distribution*.$$\dbinom53\dfrac{6^3~8^2}{14^5}$$